# How can i get the response when i am submiting a form in UIWebView?

Tags: ios, uiwebview

As I am implementing a Webpage load in the `UIWebView` ,where the user has to fill the form and have to click the submit button. During submitting the request  I am sending a return url to webpage along with the request.Once the request validates at the website end if return back to my return url.along with this it is sending some parameters.

It is successfully happening,but i am not getting that parameters.How can i get those parameters.

I have implemented the delegate method,but is not giving the parameters.

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
```

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: @Jaeger  NO,i am not using

Comment: in that case in your delegate method keep checking for the parameters as soon as you receive the parameter trim it and save it to any variable.
It would be more helpful if you could share the exact parameters you are getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been in the same Problem ,As iOS webview is not have as much functionality like in the android ,as in android  there is **JavaScriptInterface**.But there is a method in iOS to execute the JS that is stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString.

As you mention you are getting the parameters on the return url then your web developer have to get that parameters(i don't know how he will do ,but my developer did this and converted all the parameters in string) and to store in string parameter.then you can get that value using a JS Function.

```
    NSURL *requestURL = [self.WebView.request URL];
    NSLog(@"Reuest URl here is:%@",requestURL);

    NSString *javaScript = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"function givResponse(){var x=document.getElementById('div-id').innerHTML;return x; } givResponse(); "];
    NSString *jsonString = [self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:javaScript];
    NSLog(@"The returned value is %@",jsonString);

  /* Converting the string to JSON */
    NSData *data = [jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
   id json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
   NSLog(@"Here the JSon String from the respose is :%@",json);
```